# What verb do I use with ‘hobby’?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

“I can’t wait to go back home and [verb] my hobbies!”

In the above sentence, what verb do I use to convey the meaning that I would be able to perform my hobbies upon reaching my home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A phrasal verb very commonly used with "hobbies" is "take up."

Other possibilities include "resume," "enjoy," and "pursue."